# Doubt regarding spring block system

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, spring

[image]

The first picture shows a spring in natural state attached to a block. The second picture shows that the block has been compressed by $x$ distance. Now,we already know that if we release the block,it will start to perform SHM around the mean point and will only reach the $x$ distance in positive axis as amplitude. But let us try to analyze this:

We use work energy theorem when the block is at the right extreme. Now, since the block is at a compressed state, hence when it will be released,it will have an initial velocity $v$ which will be equal to $\frac{1}{2}kx^2=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$. Now the right extreme,is our final position where our velocity is $0$. So by work energy theorem, net work done on body=kinetic energy done on block or, (work done by spring from $-x$ to $0$+work done by spring from $0$ to $+x$)=change in kinetic energy=$0-\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ or
$$\int_{-x}^{0} kx\mathrm{d}x+\int_{0}^{x} -kx \mathrm{d}x=0-\frac{1}{2}mv^2$$.

But the left hand side gives answer $0$,while the right hand side has a term $-\frac{1}{2}mv^2$,which is obviously not $0$ from the relation $\frac{1}{2}mv^2=\frac{1}{2}kx^2$. Could anyone please point out where i made the mistake and provide me with the correct concept?

Comment: Your initial velocity is zero. You ${\it release}$ the block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We use work energy theorem when the block is at the right extreme.

Your equation is incorrect. It should read

$$\int_{-x}^{0} kx\mathrm{d}x+\int_{0}^{x} -kx \mathrm{d}x=0\tag{1}$$

Because the initial velocity of the block is zero at $-x$ and the final velocity is zero at $+x$ for a net change in kinetic energy of zero. From the work energy principle the *net* work done on the block equals its change in kinetic energy. In this case, the net work done is zero.

It may be helpful to break the motion into two parts:

First going from $-x$ to $0$ the initial velocity is zero and the spring does positive work equaling the increase in kinetic energy per the work energy theorem, i.e., a

$$\int_{-x}^{0} kx\mathrm{d}x=+\frac{1}{2}mv^2\tag{2}$$

The work is positive because the spring force is in the same direction of the displacement. Positive work transfers energy from the spring to the block as an increase in kinetic energy equal to the loss in elastic potential energy of the spring.

Then, going from $0$ to $+x$ the spring does negative work

$$\int_0^{+x} kx\mathrm{d}x=-\frac{1}{2}mv^2\tag{3}$$

The work is negative because the spring force is in the opposite direction of the displacement. Negative work takes energy away from the block for a decrease in kinetic energy and stores it as elastic potential energy in the spring.

Adding equations (2) and (3) together, gives equation (1).

The process continues producing simple harmonic motion about the initial block position with the spring relaxed, in which the sum of the elastic potential energy of the spring and the kinetic energy of block at any given time is constant and equal to the initial elastic potential energy of the spring, all the assuming an ideal spring, no surface friction, and no air drag.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the work done by the spring is simply $\int_{x_i}^{x^f} k x dx$. Second, your initial velocity is zero. In the first half of the full swing (from $x=-|x_0|$ to $x=0$) the spring performs work on the body and the potential energy of the spring is transformed into kinetic energy of the body. In the second half ($x=0$ to $x=|x_0|$) the body performs work on the spring and its kinetic energy transforms back into potential energy of the spring.

Answer (score 2):

Your statement *. . . . . hence when it will be released,it will have an initial velocity $\bf v$* is incorrect and it should read *. . . . . when released it will have an initial velocity of $\bf zero$*?

At that initial position the spring-mass system has a potential energy of $\frac 12 kx^2$ and zero kinetic energy.
The velocity at the static equilibrium position will be given by $\frac 12 mv^2=\frac 12kx^2$ where the assumption is that the spring potential energy is zero.
The extreme on the right hand side with have zero kinetic energy and a spring potential energy of $\frac 12kx^2$.